# Computer cannot access webserver which changed IP

Tags: macos, networking, dns, osx-yosemite

Our website changed server last week. The hosting company changed the DNS entry so that our `domain-name.com` and `www.domain-name.com` point to the new server. It works perfectly fine on all but one computer.

This computer is a OSX Yosemite MacBook. On it, pinging `domain-name.com` gives a different IP from pinging `www.domain-name.com` (the first being the correct one). Running `nslookup` on both the domain and subdomain yields the correct IP, though.

At first, there were a few different DNS settings used depending on the computer. To put it out of the equation, I set everyone to use `8.8.8.8` only (some computers had a local DNS server and/or an ISP one). I made sure the DNS service on our main router is off. I reset the Windows server DNS cache. We ran `discoveryutil mdnsflushcache` and `discoveryutil udnsflushcaches` multiple times. We even reinstalled the OS at some point.

Out of ideas!

Comment: I assume you've checked your hosts file? it seems like it isn't checking DNS at all.

Comment: That was it!! Thanks! \ 

But .. .. How did that line get in there!? I've been on Linux for the past 5 years and I use this file to name all my servers at work and home. *Never* did a line appear there on its own. Baffles me. \ 

Paste it in an answer if you want the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since DNS resolves correctly for the host, but it doesn;t use that IP when connecting, it is likely that the mapping is handled in the hosts file, which is checked first, before any remote name resolution sources like DNS.

The hosts file is typically stored in OSX at `/private/etc/hosts`. See here for more info about editing the Hosts file on a Mac: http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/edit-hosts-file-mac-os-x/

Comment: I edited `/etc/hosts` directly. Didn't know there was another one. Seems to work. Thanks again.